# Can phone flashlight damage my camera sensor

Tags: flash, camera, telephone

I have an s20 ultra and today i wanted to investigate on how are then cameras set up. So i got another phone and pointed it s flashlight to the s20 ultra cameras . The phone was closed. Did i damage my cameras somehow? The sensor or anything?

Comment: A bit late to be asking AFTER you've already done it, no? Take some photos with the camera, shine the light again, take more photos and compare.

Answer (score 1):

If the tiny LED flashlight on your other phone could damage your new phone's camera, then trying to take a picture in sunlight would obliterate your phone.

Comment: That s a good point of view